# Docker container CPU allocation

Tags: docker

I have created a container:

```
docker run -c=20 -i -t  ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

I tried to use `-c` flag to control CPU usage and maximize it in 50 %. When I am running `md5sum /dev/urandom` inside container, it use up 100 % CPU in host machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-c` flag for `docker run` command modifies the container’s CPU share weighting relative to the weighting of all other running containers.

It does not restrict the container's use of CPU from the host machine.

You can use the `--cpu-quota` flag to limit CPU usage, for example:

```
$ docker run -ti  --cpu-quota=50000 ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

The `--cpu-quota` is usually used in conjunction with `--cpu-period`. Please see more details on the Docker run reference document:

https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources

Comment: I cannot start container with this flag:
`Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 34d7af589688931383975f666b5852e14ea03c5db05ec7a6ae7347171fe34fbf: [8] System error: write /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/docker-34d7af589688931383975f666b5852e14ea03c5db05ec7a6ae7347171fe34fbf.scope/cpu.cfs_quota_us: invalid argument`

Comment: It's available since docker 1.7 (https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Yes, I am using 1.8.3.

Comment: I just edited my answer and added a sample of how to run the command. I run it  in my local docker and it is working (I have docker 1.8.3).

Comment: Thanks! But I have a question about its methodology. `0` is 100 % and `50000` is 50 % usage? Why?

Comment: This could give you more details - https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-bwc.txt. I am not sure why docker chose 0 as the default for 100%, technically based on the link above it should be -1. Anyway, 50000 is 50% CPU usage since the default period is 100000. The link I sent explains better the relationship between quota and period. Basically you limit the quota (in micro seconds) during a period (also in micro seconds). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you are running a single container, so this is the expected result.

You might find [this](https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/) blog post helpful.

> Every new container will have 1024 shares of CPU by default. This
>   value does not mean anything, when speaking of it alone. But if we
>   start two containers and both will use 100% CPU, the CPU time will be
>   divided equally between the two containers because they both have the
>   same CPU shares (for the sake of simplicity I assume that there are no
>   other processes running).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here, this is apparently what you were looking for:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpu-period-constraint

The default CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) period is 100ms. We can use --cpu-period to set the period of CPUs to limit the container’s CPU usage. And usually --cpu-period should work with --cpu-quota.

Examples:

```
$ docker run -it --cpu-period=50000 --cpu-quota=25000 ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

If there is 1 CPU, this means the container can get 50% CPU worth of run-time every 50ms.

#### period and quota definition:

Within
each given "period" (microseconds), a group is allowed to consume only up to
"quota" microseconds of CPU time.  When the CPU bandwidth consumption of a
group exceeds this limit (for that period), the tasks belonging to its
hierarchy will be throttled and are not allowed to run again until the next
period.